# Random Walks in directed graphs

Tags: probability, graph-theory, random-walk

In a random walk on a directed graph, at each step a new vertex $y$ is chosen from neighbours
of the previous vertex $x$ that are connected by outgoing edges $(x, y)$ but not incoming edges
$(y, x)$.

I need to prove that we can't do the following:

Assuming that I have a fair coin, and I'm at a certain vertex $u$, let $X$ be the set of nodes adjacent to $u$. I can use the coin to generate a binary number $2^n > |X|$ such that the probability of it corresponding to a particular node is $2^{-n}$. Hence I keep flipping the coin n times till the number I get is $<=$ $|X|$ (All nodes in $|X|$ have an equal probability of showing up, but I'm not sure if this counts as choosing "uniformly at random"?).

I then move to the vertex I get through the coin flips.

Why would this not work in a directed graph? I know that for an undirected graph this would work as a random walk of length $4n^3$ beginning at s visits all vertices in the connected component of
$s$ with probability at least $1/2$, so I can use probability amplification to boost the probability for it.

But there's no such theorem for a directed graph, and I'm trying to figure out how to disprove this algorithm for it. Also, Does it help if we allow the random walk to return to the start vertex u specified in the reachability instance, with some probability (at each step)

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please try to format your posts using mathjax:
https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference (for this post, just putting dollar signs around all the math formula will mostly do the trick)

Comment: Sorry - I've edited the post now!

Comment: Awesome, thanks. One thing to be aware of with directed graphs is that there are different kinds of connected components. You might get `stuck' in a part of the graph with no way to get back. What you'd probably want to do is see what this algorithm does on *strongly connected* digraphs.

Comment: I'd assume that you'd be able to visit every single node within a strongly connected component in walks of large enough length (assuming that you don't end up in another strongly connected component during the walk). Maybe something like if you consider the DAG of SCCs, you're very likely to end up in an SCC which does not lead to any other SCCs and you end up visiting all nodes in that SCC with a high probability for walks which are large enough?

Comment: What do you mean by "can't do" and "would not work"? You seem to have some unstated goal that you want this procedure to achieve. You can certainly do what you describe, it might just not have the effect that you want it to have, but then you need to tell us what effect that is.

Comment: Sorry I should've been more specific - by "would not work" I mean that the procedure described would not be able to find if some given node $t$ is reachable from $s$ with a high enough probability in a directed graph (while it can find if $t$ is reachable from $s$ with a high enough probability in an undirected graph)

Comment: I don't see why that shouldn't work. Who says so?

Comment: As @BrandonduPreez described above, we can be stuck in an SCC without $t$ such that there's no path from our current SCC to the SCC containing $t$. A simpler example would be a graph with 4 nodes with edges (1,2),(1,3),(1,4), the probability of ending up in one of the nodes from the root is 1/3. WLOG let $t$ = 2, a random walk of length <= 4n^3 no longer guarantees that we'll visit all nodes within the component of the root with p>=1/2, as we can end up in nodes 3 or 4 with probability 2/3, following which we're stuck (and can't visit node 2, hence there's no guarantee of visiting $t$).

Comment: Well, that just means that that node isn't reachable from the starting node. As you wrote above, in the undirected case the same thing happens – you reach all the reachable nodes, eventually with high probability. If you want to reach an entire weakly connected component, then of course you also have to allow steps along edges in the other direction. The algorithm just has to use the same notion of "reachable" as the one you're trying to achieve.